# The cancel package doesn't work sometimes in Hebrew

Tags: babel, hebrew, right-to-left, cancel

I use `babel` to write documents in Hebrew, and I use the `cancel` package to draw lines on terms in an equation for cancelation. Until now, this has been working fine. Recently, I tried to cancel a term, and instead of drawing a line over the term, it drew a bunch of arrows:

[image]

Here's the relevant code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}


\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}

% For Hebrew
\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% For English
% \babelprovide[main, import]{english}
% \babelprovide[import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}

\usepackage[hyperref, table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}

% Cancel settings
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\[ \cancel{x} + 1 - \cancel{x} = 1 \]
\[ \cancel{
    (\nabla{\psi}^{\ast})
    \cdot
    (\nabla\psi)
} \]
\end{document}
```

The weird thing is that it sometimes does that and sometimes draws a line just fine, as you can see in the picture. I couldn't figure out the pattern of when it works and when it draws those weird arrows. After playing with it, I found that the problem is probably because of Hebrew being the main language. When I change the `babel` settings to make English the main language, the problem goes away:

[image]

The changes for English:

```latex
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=english]{babel}

% For Hebrew
% \babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
% \babelprovide[import]{english}

% For English
\babelprovide[main, import]{english}
\babelprovide[import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
```

Can someone explain why the `\cancel` command sometimes works in Hebrew and sometimes not, and how I can fix this?

Comment: `$\cancel{\hspace{7ex}\Pi}$` fail but  `$\cancel{\hspace{6ex}\Delta}$`  work. Very strange.

Comment: I'm afraid that `picture` mode is broken when `bidi` is used with `babel`.

Comment: - \bcancel seems fine
- \cancel{123456} seems fine; \cancel{1234567} fails

I guess it's something to do with hebrew being left-to-right, but why it should only kick in at a certain length?

Comment: @MairAW because only at certain angles it use the glyph at the position of the `(`  (bidi exchanges `(` and `)`)

Comment: can you get \cancelto to break, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I’ve [opened an issue](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/279), I’m aware graphical elements and math elements, which are intrinsically LTR (or rather they shouldn’t change depending on the direction), are problematic, because many commands and packages must be patched (fortunately with `luatex` things are simpler than with `xetex`). For this reason, the macro `\babelsublr` is provided, which often, but not always, may help. In this case, the following change prints the expected result:

```tex
\[ \babelsublr{ \cancel{
    (\nabla{\psi}^{\ast})
    \cdot
    (\nabla\psi)
} }\]
```

**Edit.** Note `babel`, as stated in its manual, supports the `picture` environment with `pict2e`. Sadly, `\cancel` does not use the `picture` environment, and it emulates instead its original behavior, so that `pict2e` has no effect. (There is even a note in the `.tex` file about the latter: “Sometime maybe find a better solution that uses all slopes with pict2e”).

Answer (score 8):

The char for the line segment at a certain angle is stored at the position of the `(`. As bidi mirrors the `(` and the `)` you sometimes get the char stored at the `)` position, which is an arrow head.

You can disabling the mirroring, but it looks as if this can currently only be done between paragraphs. That means you need to be careful not to affect text (see the parentheses in the second text line):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}

% For Hebrew
\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% For English
% \babelprovide[main, import]{english}
% \babelprovide[import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}

\usepackage[hyperref, table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}

% Cancel settings
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

אלף (בית) גימל;

\babeladjust{bidi.mirroring=off}

אלף (בית) גימל;

\[ \cancel{x} + 1 - \cancel{x} = 1 \]
\[ \cancel{
    (\nabla{\psi}^{\ast})
    \cdot
    (\nabla\psi)
} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So I basically have to enclose every equation with `\babeladjust{bidi.mirroring=off}` and `\babeladjust{bidi.mirroring=on}`? It doesn't seem like a maintainable solution.

Comment: well you need it only if the error appears. But it is only a temporary work-around: The babel maintainer is already aware of the problem, and will probably find a way to exclude the font from the mirroring, see https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/279

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I get an error: `Package babel Error: Currently, bidi related features can be adjusted only in the main vertical list..`

Comment: I wrote above that "this can currently only be done between paragraphs". You will have to leave with this restriction until the babel maintainer adjusts the code and properly support the font used by the cancel code.

Comment: I understand. thanks

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `picture` mode is broken when `bidi` is used with `babel`.

Minimal example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}

% For Hebrew
\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% For English
% \babelprovide[main, import]{english}
% \babelprovide[import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}


\begin{document}

XXX\begin{picture}(10,10)
\line(6,1){33}
\end{picture}

\selectlanguage{english}

XXX\begin{picture}(10,10)
\line(6,1){33}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Possible workaround (may have bad effects on the bounding box, if you use `\cancelto`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\let\OriginalPictureCmds\relax
\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}

% For Hebrew
\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% For English
% \babelprovide[main, import]{english}
% \babelprovide[import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}


% Cancel settings
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\[ \cancel{x} + 1 - \cancel{x+y+z+t} = 1 \]

\[ \cancel{
    (\nabla{\psi}^{\ast})
    \cdot
    (\nabla\psi)
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Basically, we tell `cancel` that extended `picture` mode is good.

[image]

On the other hand, nothing is needed if you use `bidi=basic-r`, but this might have other side effects.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic-r, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}

% For Hebrew
\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% For English
% \babelprovide[main, import]{english}
% \babelprovide[import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}


% Cancel settings
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\[
 \cancel{x} + 1 - \cancel{x+y+z+t} = 1 \]

\[ \cancel{
    (\nabla{\psi}^{\ast})
    \cdot
    (\nabla\psi)
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting that using `bidi=basic-r` works. What's the difference between this and `bidi=basic` and should I use `bidi=basic-r` if the main language of the document is Hebrew? (I still need English here and there)

Comment: @ShaiAvr If I understand correctly, `basic-r` should become the choice, when it's out of experimental support.